# vTiger 7.3.0 lead pagination next button is not working and it shows a different number of leads in each page

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

The first page of the table shows 19 leads when the configured setting is 20, the second page shows 13 and the third page shows 11, the rest of the pages show 11 to 14 leads.

The next page button is enabled but nothing happens when clicked. To view other pages i have to enter the page number manually.

It all works correctly when the table is ordered by lead creation date, but only in descending order.

I already checked code files that have to do with pagination and lead quantity but have found nothing. i also compared files with a working vTiger instance and there's no difference.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Eduardo, try to remove other module fields from the Listview and check again. It should work. If that is not the case, add a screenshot of the Leads page with all fields visible.